# How to show the time and date saved in my database to the user according to their local timezone? Please see details

Tags: android, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat, android-date

I'm developing an app in which I'm saving the date and time in `Firebase` and then retrieving it for the user to see.

What I want is I want user to see that time and date according to their local timezone. for ex - if the time and date saved in database is '2:07 PM' and 'Fri, Jun 24', then to the users in PST timezone, it should be shown as '1:37 AM' and 'Fri, Jun 24'.

Here's how I'm getting time and date:

```
        DateFormat currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        final String time = currentTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        DateFormat currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d");
        final String date = currentDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

How can I achieve this?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
Date myDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("DateAndTimeToBeProcessed");
```